# Stop an in-progress passive scan in OWASP ZAP 2.9

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, owasp, zap

I would like to know if anyone knows how to stop or speed-up an in-progress ZAP passive scan on version 2.9. I have a 64000+ passive scan queue and it is not draining fast at all.
I have disabled all of the passive scan rules by going to Options -> Passive Scan Rules and setting the threshold to "OFF" on everything.

The console log is saying the following over and over - of course with different times and different URLs

`[ZAP-PassiveScanner] WARN org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.PassiveScanThread  - Passive Scan rule html_mailto took 211 seconds to scan https://[target-site-url]`

Answer (score 1):

If your session is already persisted then just exit. ZAP will tell you there's still a bunch of stuff to passive scan but you can say you don't care and exit anyway.

There's also this long standing enhancement ticket: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/3813 if you feel up for contributing and making things even better.

Comment: Is there not another way, I want to ensure I save my current session state and I can't do that during a scan like this.

Comment: A PR was recently accepted to allow clearing of the Passive Scan queue. Which should facilitate what you're after I believe. https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/pull/7475 It'll be available in next week's weekly build or the upcoming 2.12 release.